# UITableView, only showing UITableViewCells with data

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that takes up a portion of the screen.  However, when there is only one row of data, I'd like the UITableView (that I dropped in with IB), to shrink and only show the one row.  Is there a way for the UITableView to redraw itself?  Thanks.

Comment: How do you intend to use rest of the screen estate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the tableView height using the following code:

```
CGRect newFrame = tableView.frame;

frame.size.height = newHeight;

tableView.frame = newFrame;
```

If you want to animate the height change you need to do:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

CGRect newFrame = tableView.frame;

frame.size.height = newHeight;

tableView.frame = newFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

You can put all of the above code in a method which you can call when your `numberOfRowsInSection` data source method returns a value of 1.

Comment: Does almost everything inherit from UIView, and they all have a frame property?

Comment: Well not everything.... but as a rule of thumb, anything you can add as a subview, inherits from UIView.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much there, except my outer view that my UITableView is in doesn't shrink.  I tried doing the same thing, and it shrinks everything so it doesn't look right.  I'm guessing I need to do the same thing, but need to get the correct math?

Comment: You might want to shrink the outerview first and then resize the tableView based on the outerview's frame. When I'm dealing with view heirarchies, what I usually do is set my outermost view's frame and then in this outermost view's layoutSubviews method (you should look this one up it's useful) I set all the subview frames based on that one outermost view's frame. This way, changing only the outermost view's frame initiates layoutSubviews and resizes everything else inside the outermost view, without you having to worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the tableView frame property to match the required height