# Resizing UITableView frame based on data

Tags: iphone, uitableview

From an earlier post [UITableView, only showing UITableViewCells with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114722/uitableview-only-showing-uitableviewcells-with-data), I was able to resize my UITableView accordingly.  I do this resizing in the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I declare a CGRect originalFrame to hold my original tableView size because I was getting a problem where if I went from smaller to larger rows (i.e. 1 to 5 rows), the 5 rows would then show in 1 row space only instead of the 5.  So in my viewDidLoad method, I reset the tableView.frame to the originalFrame.  It pretty much works.  However, the nuance I see now is, it still remembers the last selection when loading the table, then when you touch the table, it reloads correctly.  For example, let's say I am showing 3 rows of data, then I move to a selection that has 5 rows of data.  When the UITableView reloads, it first only shows 3 rows worth of data, then when I touch the UITableView, the next two rows magically appear, and it works like normal.  It only happens if I go from smaller to larger.  If I start out at a selection that has 5 rows of data, it looks fine.  Then I go to a smaller selection that has 3 rows of data, then it automatically resizes to 3 rows.  Any thoughts?  Am I not redrawing at the right time?  Am I putting my resizing in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

after you adjust the frame.